# create a type with a constructor that takes in a string and a list

Tags: f#

I want to extend a type `ExprTree` (expression tree) with a new constructor `App` that takes in a string and a list as arguments. Below is the type `ExprTree`:

```
type ExprTree =
    | Const of int
    | Ident of string
    | Sum of ExprTree * ExprTree
    | Let of string * ExprTree * ExprTree
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks.....I tried the constructor |App of string*((ExprTree) list) since the list can contain other constructors of type ExprTree like ident of string or const int but it wasn't correct though

Comment: What do you mean "it wasn't correct"? Please be specific.

Comment: When i did something similar using the "sum" constructor, i get:            >Sum(Const 2, Const 2);;
val it : ExprTree = Sum (Const 2,Const 2)   --------      which is correct .                                                                 But when i try something similar using the constructor App:                               |App of string*((ExprTree) list)            I get an error:  C:\Users\tamo lucien\AppData\Local\Temp\stdin(7,10): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'ExprTree'    
but here has type
    ''a list'

Comment: `| App of string * ExprTree list`

Comment: Thanks Bent Tranberg. It worked.......I just needed to keep away the brackets

Answer (score 1):

The definition that you posted in a comment is correct. Your version from the comments was:

```
type ExprTree =
    | Const of int
    | Ident of string
    | Sum of ExprTree * ExprTree
    | Let of string * ExprTree * ExprTree
    | App of string * ((ExprTree) list)
```

The definition of the `App` constructor has some unnecessary parentheses - you do not need any and can write just `string * ExprTree list`, but they do not hurt eihter. I suspect that the issue was not with the definition, but with how you use the constructor. The following is the right syntax:

```
App("foo", [Const 1; Ident "x"])
```